# Android Room querys not finding databaseViews in DAO

Tags: java, android, android-room

Room is not finding views even tough the database inspector can execute the query just fine:
[database inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VShCs.png)
No matter what it gives me this error:
[Room cant seem to find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8aAc.png)

This is my view class

```
package Vistas;

import androidx.room.DatabaseView;

@DatabaseView("SELECT Alumno.id_alumno,Alumno.primer_apellido_alumno,Alumno.segundo_apellido_alumno,Alumno.nombre_alumno,Matricula.ano_matricula, Grado.nombre_grado FROM Alumno JOIN Matricula ON Alumno.id_alumno = Matricula.id_alumno_matricula JOIN Grado ON Grado.id_grado = Matricula.id_grado_matricula")
public class AlumnoVista {
    public Integer alumnoId;
    public String primerApellido;
    public String segundoApellido;
    public String nombreAlumno;
    public String nombreGrado;
    public Integer anoMatricula;
}
```

This is my database class

```
package Controlador;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.DatabaseConfiguration;
import androidx.room.InvalidationTracker;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper;

import Vistas.AlumnoVista;
import entidades.Alumno;
import entidades.Asignatura;
import entidades.Centro;
import entidades.Grado;
import entidades.Matricula;
import entidades.Nota;
import entidades.Profesor;
import entidades.Usuario;
import entidadesDao.AlumnoDao;
import entidadesDao.AsignaturaDao;
import entidadesDao.CentroDao;
import entidadesDao.MatriculaDao;
import entidadesDao.NotaDao;
import entidadesDao.ProfesorDao;
import entidadesDao.UsuarioDao;
import entidadesDao.GradoDao;

@androidx.room.Database(entities = {Alumno.class, Asignatura.class, Centro.class, Profesor.class, Usuario.class, Nota.class, Matricula.class, Grado.class},
        views = {AlumnoVista.class},
        version=5, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class BaseDatos extends RoomDatabase {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "database";
    private static BaseDatos instance;

    public abstract AlumnoDao alumnoDao();

    public abstract GradoDao gradoDao();

    public abstract CentroDao centroDao();

    public abstract AsignaturaDao asignaturaDao();

    public abstract ProfesorDao profesorDao();

    public abstract UsuarioDao usuarioDao();

    public abstract MatriculaDao matriculaDao();

    public abstract NotaDao notaDao();

    public static BaseDatos getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), BaseDatos.class, DB_NAME).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().createFromAsset("database.db").build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void clearAllTables() {

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected InvalidationTracker createInvalidationTracker() {
        return null;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(@NonNull DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

And this is my dao

```
package entidadesDao;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

import Vistas.AlumnoVista;
import entidades.Alumno;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Completable;
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable;

@Dao
public interface AlumnoDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    public Completable insertAlumno(Alumno alumno);

    @Update
    public Completable updateAlumno(Alumno alumno);

    @Delete
    public Completable deleteAlumno(Alumno alumno);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Alumno ORDER BY primer_apellido_alumno ASC")
    public Flowable<List<Alumno>> getAlumnosByFirstName();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM AlumnoVista")
    public List<AlumnoVista> getAlumnosVista();

}
```

I tried incresing the database version number, redoing the view multiple times ,building and cleaning the project and using the viewName attribute in the view.

Answer (score 0):

When generating an object Room expects to match the fields of the object with the column names that are output by the query.

You have a field name **alumnoId** but there is no such column in the output, instead it appears that the output that should match is named **id_alumo** and so on.

One solution would be to alias the output column using an AS ? clause e.g.

```
SELECT Alumno.id_alumno AS alumnoId, ....
```

- so the **id_alumno** column is output as **alumnId** thus matching the **alumnoId** field in the **AlumnoVista** object
- and likewise so all column names match the field name.

So perhaps:-

```
SELECT Alumno.id_alumno AS alumnoId,Alumno.primer_apellido_alumno AS primerApellido,Alumno.segundo_apellido_alumno AS segundoApellido,Alumno.nombre_alumno AS nombreAlumno,Matricula.ano_matricula AS anoMatricula, Grado.nombre_grado AS nombreGrado FROM Alumno JOIN Matricula ON Alumno.id_alumno = Matricula.id_alumno_matricula JOIN Grado ON Grado.id_grado = Matricula.id_grado_matricula
```

- note untested so there might be typos.
- the `AS` keyword aliases (renames) the column that is output

An alternative approach would be to tell the fields what column to expect by using the ***name*** parameter of the `@ColumnInfo` annotation e.g.

```
@DatabaseView("SELECT Alumno.id_alumno,Alumno.primer_apellido_alumno,Alumno.segundo_apellido_alumno,Alumno.nombre_alumno,Matricula.ano_matricula, Grado.nombre_grado FROM Alumno JOIN Matricula ON Alumno.id_alumno = Matricula.id_alumno_matricula JOIN Grado ON Grado.id_grado = Matricula.id_grado_matricula")
public class AlumnoVista {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_alumno")
    public Integer alumnoId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "primer_apellido_alumno")
    public String primerApellido;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "segundo_apellido_alumno")
    public String segundoApellido;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nombre_alumno")
    public String nombreAlumno;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nombre_grado")
    public String nombreGrado;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ano_matricula")
    public Integer anoMatricula;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did what Mike suggested and changed my view class. However the error of room not finding "AlumnoVista" in my querys persisted.

To "fix" it , I first implemented the method manually in the autogenerated class (AlumnoDao_Impl) and second I told room to not check the query before runtime.

Because the query works on the database inspector (see the first image i posted) I imagine that this is an error of room incorrectly checking the query before runtime.

Until someone confirms that this is indeed an error or informs me that I of something else that I did incorrectly I will leave this question as unsolved.Since my way of "fixing" is more of a band aid than a actual fix.